# What can make signal.signal block for a long time?

Tags: python, signals

I am registering a signal for remote debugging:

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, lambda x,y: remote_debug(x, y, emp_id))

While normally very fast, log statements show this command (register) sometimes takes 5 to 10 seconds to execute.  What is causing this? How can I fix it?

Comment: do you use threads in your program?

Comment: no threading when handler is registered

Comment: What platform?  If Linux try running `strace python myscript.py` and study the output.

Comment: update: Seems like that line was a red herring. After commenting it out, the second log message (which immediately follows the first), is sometimes delayed by 5 seconds. My current hypothesis is that the first log message could somehow be tied up in flush. I do an os.setreuid right before the first log message; perhaps that can slow down flushing somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The Python callback code is not actually called right away in Python. The C code in Python just sets a flag when it gets a signal. It only runs the handler when it returns to the interpreter. If your code path is currently working in an extension module in compiled code the handler won't get run until it finishes.

The only way to fix it is to ensure that the execution path doesn't spend a lot of time in a C function. What function are you running at that time? Another culprit is the standard time.sleep() method. Use signal.pause() instead.

Comment: Sorry this command may have been unclear. I'm not asking about the callback time. Running signal.signal(..) to *register* the signal handler is taking 5-10 seconds.